# Files showing in file explorer but not in the open file window

Tags: google-chrome

Really annoying behavior, I had files which did not appear in the "open file" box.
I struggled a bit until I discovered the behavior ...

Comment: Is this question really about `nautilus` (the default gnome file manager) - or does the behavior you are describing occur when using the open file dialog of another application?

Comment: open file dialog of another application (chrome). is not nautilus ?

Comment: Not afaik - though they likely use the same underlying [Gtk fileChooser](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/iface.FileChooser.html) widget

Answer (score -4, accepted):

The files didn't have extensions.
Files without extensions are filtered from the "open file" window.
I guess that's some "security feature".
Chrome design it seems.
Great design.

Comment: That''s likely **by design** of the application you're using to "open file".  A lot of applications will filter by file type and such.  However, this question and answer pair is more of just 'complaining' than an actual question/answer pair.

Comment: please don't use profane language on this site.  However, the point still stands - a LOT of applications have "Open File" and specify extensions or file types to restrict what you can upload in a very basic way.  But it's still something to keep in mind **you will encounter this in numerous areas, and it's not Ubuntu's fault..